# How to install an older version of a package not entirely intended for your Ubuntu version?

Tags: apt, package-management, versions

I have Lubuntu 19.04. The latest Inkscape is unstable (crashes often) even though it's from the stable package.

The latest Gimp 2.10 is very stable (as are most versions I've tried through the years with Ubuntu), but threw me for a loop in how the theme and icons have to be switched to make them more legacy, and the blur filter functionality has changed dramatically and is not as easy.

The last Inkscape I loved and which was stable was the following, and it came from Ubuntu 14.04:

```
inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 Jan 22 2014
0.48.4-3ubuntu2
```

The last Gimp I loved and which was stable was the following, and also shipped with Ubuntu 14.04:

```
gimp 2.8.10
2.8.10-0ubuntu1.2
```

I tried installing only the old versions of these by doing:

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get --purge remove inkscape
apt-get --purge remove gimp
apt-get install inkscape=0.48.4-3ubuntu2
apt-get install gimp=2.8.10-0ubuntu1.2
```

However, it said that it couldn't find these versions in the default PPA.

How do I get around this to install the version I want, even though it's Lubuntu 19.04? Or, is there a way I can do this with a **snap** instead of an **apt package** ?

Comment: default PPA?  PPA=personal package archive or a 3rd party software source where none are included by default as only official Ubuntu repositories are used at install.

Comment: I downloaded gimp_2.8.10-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb from the ubuntu pool and `sudo dpkg -i --dry-run` to see what issues I got, but the only warning was `dpkg: warning: downgrading gimp from 2.10.8-2 to 2.8.10-0ubuntu1.2` on my Lubuntu (19.10).  I doubt it would negatively impact Lubuntu which is LXQt based, gimp is still GTK+2 I believe but I don't know of any other effects, so I'd treat this as a less than ideal solution.  I didn't find snaps that old.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PPA and installed packages from it. Now try manually adding the *trusty* version of the PPA:

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/developer-name/ppa-name/ubuntu/ trusty main"` (where *developer-name* and *ppa-name* are placeholders).

This *should* work, assuming the PPA has support for the *trusty* release, however it has **not** been tested on our end. If the command fails (which it might), you can undo it with the same command, but add the `--remove` tag after it.